# textContent property not updating with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making the calculator app as part of The Odin Project. I have a javascript function that performs the required calculation:

```
function doCalc(arr) {
    //CHECK IF INPUT IS VALID. IF SO, PERFORM CALCULATION
    if (checkValid(arr)) {
        if (arr.length === 1)
            return arr;

        arr = getResultArr(arr, "/");
        arr = getResultArr(arr, "*");
        arr = getResultArr(arr, "+");
        arr = getResultArr(arr, "-");
        if (arr[0] == "Infinity")
            arr[0] = "ERROR: DIVISION BY 0";

        return (input = arr);
    }

    else {
        //THIS IS THE LINE GIVING TROUBLE
        inputText.textContent = "INVALID CALCULATION";
    }

}
```

The function first checks to see if the input in the calculator is valid. For example, entering "9++3" is invalid because of the two plus signs together. If it's not valid, it goes to the "else" branch then is supposed to update `textContent` of the `inputText` element (which refers to a p tag).

However, the text of the p tag never actually updates. It stays the same. When I put a break point in the Chrome debugger, the line gets executed just fine (as I step through the "else" branch), which is weird. Also, if I change the code to alter other properties of the `inputText` element, it works. For example, I can change the line in question to `inputText.style.cssText = "background-color: blue;";` and it will work just fine. But if I try to change the text using `textContent`, or even `innerText` or `innerHTML` it doesn't work.

Any idea what's going on?

EDIT: Just to add, the javascript file is imported into my html file at the bottom, so it is ran after the DOM is created. Also, the `inputText` element works just fine, including updating its `textContent` elsewhere in the code. I can also update its `textContent` just fine in the console.

Comment: It sounds like something else is clearing the `inputText` contents after this function runs. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Barmar You were right. I figured it out after seeing your comment. Thank you.